# Can I embed a YouTube video without any links to YouTube on top of the video?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, youtube

I need a way to show a YouTube video on my page. I don't need to show the link on top of the video which appears when you hover the mouse over it. I don't want the suggestions of other videos at the end of the video, I just want the *replay* button, but not the bunch of other related videos.

Comment: You actually mean: "I want to use someone else's free service to host my video, but I don't want to let them subsidize this by highlighting their brand on MY video! SCREW YOU GUSY!#$!"

Comment: why are you guys getting worked up !? maybe you havent seen http://gizmodo.com ?check out the youtube videos on that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know you could do this but if you take a look at gizmodo's source you'll find a specially crafted youtube video link similar to:

http://www.youtube.com/v/0zxxM9EYQzY?hl=en&fs=1&hd=1

This style of link seems to have no top link and no video suggestions at the end.  Whether you're permitted to use such links is another story.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those links, buttons and garbage are how Youtube justifies putting your video out for free (It's not really free at all, is it?)  If you were to figure out some way to hack into Youtube it would be stealing just the same as if you bought some app, copied it and handed it to your customers.

If you want a service that can publish your video without their own terms then I suggest you plan to pay for the bandwidth, at that point you will find many companies willing to "Help" you do it exactly the way you want.

Comment: not sure you get my point sir !please check gizmodo.com  out and the  youtube videos on that !

Comment: My guess is that gizmodo pays youtube for the privilege of the videos looking that way.  Try embedding the link from James' answer in your own web server and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but the little guy has no choice but to suffer the burden of promoting youtube with all of the extra crud. If Gizmodo - as you mention - don't have such faecal adornments, then that's because they're a "big guy," drawing significant viewers from views directly in youtube which probably offsets the loss in exposure through embedded videos.

TL;DR - if you have a lot of viewers, this is probably a feature you get/earn for free (removing adornments in embedded view)